I have two different LTE setups failing to initialize or turn on with the exact same errors
Device 1:
Quectel RM520N-GL 5G

connected to
https://www.ebay.com/itm/165783027282
One of these. Which has a waveshare logo on it
Device 2:
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B09LV1VY4S?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_fed_asin_title
Connected to
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0D833S99L?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_fed_asin_title
Which also has Waveshare printed on the board.
I can see that the devices are connected
Device 1:
Ubuntu-Inspiron-5502:/home/user# mmcli -v --modem 0
[07 Dec 2024, 22:47:05] [Debug] ModemManager process found at ':1.1745'
[07 Dec 2024, 22:47:05] [Debug] Assuming '0' is the modem index
[07 Dec 2024, 22:47:05] [Debug] Modem found at '/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0'

[07 Dec 2024, 22:47:05] [Debug] Printing modem info...
  -------------------------
  General |           path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
  -------------------------
  System  |         device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.4
          |        physdev: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.4
          |        drivers: cdc_acm, cdc_ncm
          |         plugin: generic
          |   primary port: ttyACM0
          |          ports: enx000011121314 (net), enx000011121316 (net), 
          |                 enx000011121318 (net), ttyACM0 (at)
  -------------------------
  Status  |          state: failed
          |  failed reason: unknown-capabilities
  -------------------------
  Modes   |      supported: allowed: any; preferred: none
          |        current: allowed: any; preferred: none

Device 2:
raspi5-dev1:~ $ sudo mmcli -m 0
  -------------------------
  General |           path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
  -------------------------
  System  |         device: /sys/devices/platform/axi/1000110000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-1
          |        drivers: cdc_acm, cdc_ncm
          |         plugin: generic
          |   primary port: ttyACM0
          |          ports: eth1 (net), eth2 (net), eth3 (net), ttyACM0 (at)
  -------------------------
  Status  |          state: failed
          |  failed reason: unknown-capabilities
  -------------------------
  Modes   |      supported: allowed: any; preferred: none
          |        current: allowed: any; preferred: none

I can also see the pci-e device
raspi5-dev1:~ $ sudo lspci
0000:00:00.0 PCI bridge: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM2712 PCIe Bridge (rev 21)
0000:01:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805/806 xHCI USB 3.0 Controller (rev 01)
0001:00:00.0 PCI bridge: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM2712 PCIe Bridge (rev 21)
0001:01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Raspberry Pi Ltd RP1 PCIe 2.0 South Bridge

But both are in a failed state.
They both do not create any USB interface even though both can be seen using
Device 2:
raspi5-dev1:~ $ lsusb
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:095a Intel Corp. MODEM + 2 CDC-ACM + 3 CDC-NCM + SS
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

They both create a
/dev/ttyACM0
/dev/ttyACM1
/dev/ttyACM2

interfaces:
raspi5-dev1:~ $ ls /dev
autofs           fd          hidraw2  loop5         pio0   ram2     snd         tty15  tty29  tty42  tty56    ttyAMA10   vcs6   vcsu5        video27
block            full        hwrng    loop6         port   ram3     spidev0.0   tty16  tty3   tty43  tty57    ttyprintk  vcs7   vcsu6        video28
btrfs-control    fuse        i2c-1    loop7         ppp    ram4     spidev0.1   tty17  tty30  tty44  tty58    uhid       vcsa   vcsu7        video29
bus              gpiochip0   i2c-13   loop-control  pps0   ram5     spidev10.0  tty18  tty31  tty45  tty59    uinput     vcsa1  vga_arbiter  video30
cachefiles       gpiochip10  i2c-14   mapper        ptmx   ram6     stderr      tty19  tty32  tty46  tty6     urandom    vcsa2  vhci         video31
cec0             gpiochip11  initctl  media0        ptp0   ram7     stdin       tty2   tty33  tty47  tty60    usb        vcsa3  vhost-net    video32
cec1             gpiochip12  input    media1        pts    ram8     stdout      tty20  tty34  tty48  tty61    v4l        vcsa4  vhost-vsock  video33
char             gpiochip13  kmsg     media2        ram0   ram9     tty         tty21  tty35  tty49  tty62    vcio       vcsa5  video19      video34
console          gpiomem0    kvm      mem           ram1   random   tty0        tty22  tty36  tty5   tty63    vc-mem     vcsa6  video20      video35
cpu_dma_latency  gpiomem1    log      mmcblk0       ram10  rfkill   tty1        tty23  tty37  tty50  tty7     vcs        vcsa7  video21      watchdog
cuse             gpiomem2    loop0    mmcblk0p1     ram11  rtc      tty10       tty24  tty38  tty51  tty8     vcs1       vcsu   video22      watchdog0
disk             gpiomem3    loop1    mmcblk0p2     ram12  rtc0     tty11       tty25  tty39  tty52  tty9     vcs2       vcsu1  video23      zero
dma_heap         gpiomem4    loop2    mqueue        ram13  serial   tty12       tty26  tty4   tty53  ttyACM0  vcs3       vcsu2  video24
dri              hidraw0     loop3    net           ram14  serial0  tty13       tty27  tty40  tty54  ttyACM1  vcs4       vcsu3  video25
fb0              hidraw1     loop4    null          ram15  shm      tty14       tty28  tty41  tty55  ttyACM2  vcs5       vcsu4  video26

I tried numerous ways to create a connection using
raspi5-dev1:~ $ sudo nmcli c add type gsm ifname ttyACM0 con-name modem apn internet.itelcel.com
Connection 'modem' (68311af0-7777-4d1f-9632-f83fdf8bcec4) successfully added.

But I find no method of bringing the connection live
raspi5-dev1:~ $ ifconfig -s ttyACM0 10.10.10.10 255.255.255.0
SIOCSIFADDR: Operation not permitted
ttyACM0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
SIOCSIFADDR: Operation not permitted
ttyACM0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

I can see the modem I created.
raspi5-dev1:~ $ nmcli con
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
Wired connection 1  f8137f1c-97b4-3995-b13d-4107c6d5072d  ethernet  eth0   
lo                  e8755090-189e-491a-80fc-04aef18a0d49  loopback  lo     
preconfigured       e6521720-42c4-459b-b5cd-0a3596cced4a  wifi      wlan0  
modem               68311af0-7777-4d1f-9632-f83fdf8bcec4  gsm       --

or
raspi5-dev1:~ $ mmcli -e /dev/ttyACM0
error: no modem was specified
raspi5-dev1:~ $ sudo mmcli -L
    /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 [manufacturer unknown] model unknown
raspi5-dev1:~ $ mmcli -e /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
error: no modem was specified

I can't seem to do anything with it.
FYI
raspi5-dev1:~ $ sudo ln -sft /etc/ModemManager/fcc-unlock.d /usr/share/ModemManager/fcc-unlock.available.d/*

raspi5-dev1:~ $ mbimcli -p -d /dev/ttyACM0 --quectel-query-radio-state
error: couldn't open the MbimDevice: Couldn't spawn the mbim-proxy

raspi5-dev1:~ $ mbimcli -p -d /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0 --quectel-query-radio-state
error: couldn't create MbimDevice: Couldn't query file info: Error when getting information for file “/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0”: No such file or directory

raspi5-dev1:~ $ mmcli -m 0 --command='AT+CFUN=0?'
error: command failed: 'GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Error.Core.Unauthorized: PolicyKit authorization failed: not authorized for 'org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Device.Control''

raspi5-dev1:~ $ ls -al /dev/serial/by-id
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 100 Dec  7 22:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  80 Dec  7 16:59 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 Dec  7 22:37 usb-Intel_Corp._MODEM_+_2_CDC-ACM_+_3_CDC-NCM_+_SS_004999010640000:004999010640000:004999010640000:004999010640000-if00 -> ../../ttyACM0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 Dec  7 22:37 usb-Intel_Corp._MODEM_+_2_CDC-ACM_+_3_CDC-NCM_+_SS_004999010640000:004999010640000:004999010640000:004999010640000-if02 -> ../../ttyACM1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 Dec  7 22:37 usb-Intel_Corp._MODEM_+_2_CDC-ACM_+_3_CDC-NCM_+_SS_004999010640000:004999010640000:004999010640000:004999010640000-if04 -> ../../ttyACM2

I tried emailing Waveshare asking them how to turn the device on and they replied with:
Your request (182472) has been updated. To add additional comments, reply all to this email.

Xin-kang
Nov 28, 2024, 11:24 UTC

Please place all switches on the OFF side：

 

Then please use the following command to check the device status：

Please use the command to check the device status：

lspci lsusb ls /dev

If you are content,please rate good!

Best wish!

I have tried to toggle the only dipswitch in the waveshare board and no dice. Everything the same.
Both have brand new Telcel sim cards installed.
Somehow I am missing how to initialize (find the on button) either of these devices.
How do I initialize an m.2 LTE device?
I also tried ctl + M and then ctl + J. That should have initialized the modem but did not.
I tried feeding "AT+CFUN=0" which shut my modem off and now I cannot see AT commands when typed in. I tried powing off for a few minutes and that did not reset it fully.
update:
udevadm info /dev/ttyACM0
P: /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.2/1-1.1.2:1.0/tty/ttyACM0
M: ttyACM0
R: 0
U: tty
D: c 166:0
N: ttyACM0
L: 0
S: serial/by-id/usb-Intel_Corp._MODEM_+_2_CDC-ACM_+_3_CDC-NCM_+_SS_004999010640000:004999010640000:004999010640000:004999010640000-if00
S: serial/by-path/platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.1.2:1.0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.2/1-1.1.2:1.0/tty/ttyACM0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/ttyACM0
E: MAJOR=166
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=tty
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=3095355242
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_MODEL=MODEM_+_2_CDC-ACM_+_3_CDC-NCM_+_SS
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=MODEM\x20+\x202\x20CDC-ACM\x20+\x203\x20CDC-NCM\x20+\x20SS
E: ID_MODEL_ID=095a
E: ID_SERIAL=Intel_Corp._MODEM_+_2_CDC-ACM_+_3_CDC-NCM_+_SS_004999010640000:004999010640000:004999010640000:004999010640000
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=004999010640000:004999010640000:004999010640000:004999010640000
E: ID_VENDOR=Intel_Corp.
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Intel\x20Corp.
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=8087
E: ID_REVISION=0350
E: ID_TYPE=generic
E: ID_USB_MODEL=MODEM_+_2_CDC-ACM_+_3_CDC-NCM_+_SS
E: ID_USB_MODEL_ENC=MODEM\x20+\x202\x20CDC-ACM\x20+\x203\x20CDC-NCM\x20+\x20SS
E: ID_USB_MODEL_ID=095a
E: ID_USB_SERIAL=Intel_Corp._MODEM_+_2_CDC-ACM_+_3_CDC-NCM_+_SS_004999010640000:004999010640000:004999010640000:004999010640000
E: ID_USB_SERIAL_SHORT=004999010640000:004999010640000:004999010640000:004999010640000
E: ID_USB_VENDOR=Intel_Corp.
E: ID_USB_VENDOR_ENC=Intel\x20Corp.
E: ID_USB_VENDOR_ID=8087
E: ID_USB_REVISION=0350
E: ID_USB_TYPE=generic
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:020201:0a0200:020200:020d00:0a0001:ff0100:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=cdc_acm
E: ID_USB_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Miscellaneous Device
E: ID_USB_PROTOCOL_FROM_DATABASE=Interface Association
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Intel Corp.
E: ID_PATH=platform-3f980000.usb-usb-0:1.1.2:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=platform-3f980000_usb-usb-0_1_1_2_1_0
E: ID_MM_CANDIDATE=1
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/serial/by-id/usb-Intel_Corp._MODEM_+_2_CDC-ACM_+_3_CDC-NCM_+_SS_004999010640000:004999010640000:004999010640000:0049990106400>
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: CURRENT_TAGS=:systemd:


The error unknown-capabilities usually indicates ModemManager cannot properly detect the modem's capabilities due to a lack of plugin support or incorrect configuration. Update ModemManager to the latest version.

@liaifat85 apt full-upgrade had no affect.
